# Use result of pandas groupby to query date from column's pandas cut date range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I've got the result of a `pandas.groupby()` call, and I'm wanting to query the result in a mysql `select` style query. Here is a MWE of the code I'm trying to work from:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

dates = np.array([dt(2012, 9, 27, 8, 52, 21),
       dt(2012, 10, 6, 5, 4, 15),
       dt(2012, 10, 7, 4, 53, 4),
       dt(2012, 10, 9, 7, 21, 18),
       dt(2012, 10, 10, 5, 4, 8),
       dt(2012, 10, 11, 4, 58, 43),
       dt(2012, 10, 12, 11, 15, 25),
       dt(2012, 10, 13, 10, 45, 23),
       dt(2012, 10, 20, 6, 0, 25),
       dt(2012, 10, 22, 7, 41, 38)])

values = np.array([5.61006523, 5.39632183, 5.49317193, 5.42327983, 5.4623386, 
                   5.42444747, 5.60362929, 5.57041331, 5.34893575, 5.48222005])

date_bins = np.array([dt(2012, 9, 29, 14),
                      dt(2012, 10, 10, 14),
                      dt(2012, 10, 14, 14),
                      dt(2012, 10, 23, 14)])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'value': values})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bin_dates':date_bins})

print(df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1['date'], df2['bin_dates'])).agg({'value':np.nanmean}))
```

Yielding:

```
                                               value
date                                                
(2012-09-29 14:00:00, 2012-10-10 14:00:00]  5.443778
(2012-10-10 14:00:00, 2012-10-14 14:00:00]  5.532830
(2012-10-14 14:00:00, 2012-10-23 14:00:00]  5.415578
```

What I am essentially doing is creating the data representation of a profile histogram with custom time binning. The question I have now is that I am trying to use the result of this to query new times (say `2012-10-11 3:00:00`) and be able to get back the mean value from that associated bin (`5.532830`). Can anyone advise me on how to do this? Is it possible within the pandas framework? Or do I need to move the data over to something like mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc`

```
s=df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1['date'], df2['bin_dates'])).agg({'value':np.nanmean})
s.loc['2012-10-11 3:00:00']
Out[94]: 
value    5.53283
Name: (2012-10-10 14:00:00, 2012-10-14 14:00:00], dtype: float64
```

Comment: Well, that was quite easy. Thanks! Do you know if it's possible to query the result using  a datetime object? Or will I have to `.strftime()` it?